# How can you minimize full screen apps in OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, fullscreen

I like keeping my windows full screen.  However, when any application is full screen, the yellow button in the upper left becomes grey and is not clickable.  How can I minimize the window without first clicking the green button to bring it back to the desktop?

Edit for clarity:
I would like the entire space to be removed when I minimize the window.

Comment: Why would you want that? Just leave them be and move to the other spaces.

Comment: They create a lot of clutter.  I don't want to have to search through every open program when I go to mission control.

Comment: You could do a two-step cmd+m to exit fullscreen, then cmd+h to hide, right?

Comment: cmd+m does not do anything.  I can press the green button then the yellow button, but I have to wait for the animation in between, and I also have to push two buttons (icon on dock then green) to get the window back to full screen.

Comment: @dta sometimes an action doesn't have a combo assigned. You can check the exit full screen action in the keyboard prefs.

Comment: It's possible to map a keyboard shortcut to exit full screen.  However, this brings the window to the desktop.  I'm looking to switch it directly to minimized or hidden.